# Default name in Drupal user login form?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

Is is possible to pre-enter the username via URL in the Drupal user page, e.g.:

```
www.example.com/user?name=peter
```

such that "peter" is filled automatically in the `Name` filed and so the user is required to enter the password only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the [Prepopulate module](http://drupal.org/project/prepopulate) is written to handle that kind of thing.

Comment: p.s. - You may also want to check out the Drupal Answers Beta site. The more people who use it, the better chance it has of making it past beta: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/